# regex to remove any string before _, except for several strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am wondering of regular expression  (preferably in notepad++) to remove `string1_` in the pattern `string1_string2`, except for several strings?

For instance, I want to get this (know and can are maintained)

```
PUNC PUNC know_X2.2+ Z5 can_A7+ can_Z5[i6.2.2 PUNC Z5
```

from this

```
<TYP 1>_PUNC &lsqb;_PUNC know_X2.2+ outside_Z5 can_A7+ can_Z5[i6.2.2 <SEX ?>_PUNC am_Z5
```

I've tried using this 
`(?<!(can_|know_))`

but did not match.

Thank you very much

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?:<[^<>]*>|[^_\s])*_(?<!can_)(?<!know_)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WfdPpd/1)

**Details**

- `(?:<[^<>]*>|[^_\s])*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `<[^<>]*>` - a `<`, then any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^_\s]` - any char other than whitespace and `_`
- `_(?<!can_)(?<!know_)` - a `_` that is not preceded with `can_` nor `know_`.

Notepad++ settings & demo:

[image]

Comment: This is magic .....  how did you do it? it's working 100% I still can't understand it, above my understandipng .... well done wiktor

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah Experience. My profile says *Visited 2312 days, 2303 consecutive*, and these consecutive days are tracking and answering regex tagged questions. BTW, if the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider upvoting the answer.

Comment: If I could I would upvote it more one time ! But why the OP did not accept it?